# Force threads to leave object before destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, destructor, blocking

When using multithreading I often run into the following problem:

I've got an object, say a network receiver(but could be anything). And a function that gets the data. Now sometimes there simply is no data, and you want to let the thread wait to get it's data. A blocking call, very much like being used by Berkeley sockets and it's derived implementations.

The principle is simple:

[image: Forgive my mediocre illustrational skills. I'm a programmer after all:)]

Well now of course there is other ways of implementing this. But my usual implementation with C++11 is as follows:

- `Object A` Calls the function in object B on a separate thread, that is dedicated to this task.
- `Object B` Uses an `std::condition_variable` construction to block the thread until the data is actually acquired.
- `Object A` Places the data in a queue, which is read out by the main thread.

Now my actual problem arises on the destruction of `object B`, if it has to be destructed before `object A`(returning a nullptr, or something similar on the blocking call). I really wouldn't know how to efficiently wrap up `object B`.

The main problem is that `object B` isn't aware of the thread, and a thread can only have one handle, which is inside `object A`.

**Example:**

Some code to illustrate my problem.

Say I've got this function in object B:

```
data* getData
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>l_newDataWaiterLock(m_newDataWaiterMutex);
    m_newDataWaiter.wait(l_newDataMutex);
    if(!running)
       return nullptr
    else 
       return data;
}
```

and this destructor:

```
~ObjectB()
{
    m_running = false;
    m_newDataWaiter.notifyAll();
    //Point X
}
```

With these member variables:

```
std::condition_variable m_newDataWaiter;
std::atomic<bool> m_running;
```

We still have the problem that the destructor will have to wait at the indicated `Point X`, until all the other threads have received the notify, and returned a null.

Now I could cook something up using atomic counters, more `std::condition_variable`s and mutexes. But I have a feeling there has to be a more elegant and reliable solution to this problem:). Since this solution would require a notify in every `getData` call for the entire lifecycle of `object B`.

**Note:** I'm using C++11, so I've used that to illustrate everything. And I'm hoping to solve it using that. Although this of course this is a more of a general concurrency problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about managing object `B` with a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and using [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to store the pointer in `A`?

That is slightly more inefficient as each time that `A` wants to get access, it temporarily needs to get a `std::shared_ptr` through [`std::weak_ptr::lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) itself, but you can be sure there is no race condition anymore.

Comment: Ah yes that would be a solution. However that would also prevent the destructor from getting called right? And therefore requiring a previous call to the `Object B` indicating is a about to be destructed. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @laurisvr That is the beauty of `std::weak_ptr`: It won't prevent the referenced object from being destructed. Only while you (temporarily) have a `std::shared_ptr` to place data into it, the destruction is prevented. Just check the result with `if( const auto sp = wp.lock() ) { sp->insert(data); }`. The overall lifetime management is hard to judge without seeing the whole code, but give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

> my actual problem arises on the destruction of object B, if it has to
>   be destructed before object A

Here I describe yet another approach to handling the delete of an object instance that might have threads running within it.  The embedded system behaviour might be too different from your design ... but perhaps it can inspire a new way of looking at your challenge.

---

Summary:  Use a waste-basket and janitor.

When time to 'remove' an object that might have other threads working in it

```
 1) copy pointer-to-object   to the 'waste-basket' fifo
    A* a;   waste_basket.push_back(a);  

 2) copy pointer-to-replacement-object to replace pointer-to-object
    A* t = new(replacementObject);
    a = t;  

 Use low priority janitor thread to inspect waste-basket periodically
 and delete any resident older than max duration. Max duratin ensures 
 any other thread activity has completed.
```

The n seconds in the waste-basket, prevents deleting of the object
  while threads are still using it.  (Your duration may differ.)

---

In an embedded system I worked on, there were 28 passive (no
internal thread) object instances in a polymorphic table (cards in
the shelf), and about 10+ threads that might, at any given time, be
interacting with the hw through one of these card instances.

Even though an operator (on a ui thread) might command the removal of instance
j (the j'th card in the shelf), the object can *not* be deleted
until all threads currently executing within are finished with their current activity.

Partly because of the brief nature of each method (< 25 ms), we did
not use counts, nor semaphores to determine the instance's not-visited
state.  Instead, we completed the remove transition in two steps,
and deferred the actual delete of the card.

step 1) copy the table entry shelf[j] to a 'waste-basket' fifo list,

step 2) replace the table entry shelf[j] with an 'empty slot'
        instance pointer, something all shelf-using-threads know how to 
        use polymorphically (as if it was just another card).

These two steps made the logical **removal appear instantaneous** to
the users and threads.  But when would the delete actually happen?

All existing threads were required to leave the instance when they 'finished' their activity. But how long might that be?

The derived requirement we came up with (based on other aspects of the design) was that any thread 'working' inside an object instance shall finish that activity in < 25 ms. On a pragmatic note, most were completed much faster, none were longer.

Thus, for this embedded system and convenience,  the team decided that the waste basket 'hold' duration would be >= 1 sec.

Note that while the removed card resided in the waste-basket, no
other thread could access it nor start another activity within that same object.  The other threads were mis-directed when they found an 'empty slot' card in the shelf.  The card was logically gone, if not yet deleted from memory.

To finish this design, we added a low priority janitor task to work the waste-basket list periodically.  The janitor inspected the arrival time of the instance into the waste basket, and did not delete any card until after at least 1 second in the queue.